# Needs to bring SQL SERVER 2008 R2 Installation window in front of WIX Bootstrapper Bundle installation window (Silent Installation)

Tags: wpf, mvvm, wix, mvvm-light, bootstrapper

I have designed bootstrap bundle window using WPF Mvvm, and I have done chain installation in the Wix BootStrapper project. All are working fine except, The SQL Server 2008 R2 installation window popup behind the Bundle install window.. When it opens it blink on Taskbar and I need to click it to bring in front. So I need to pop up the SQL Server 2008 R2 installation window in front automatically when it triggers.. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should not try to change the modality of the window, and you are doomed to failure if you try. This is because the SQL Server install actually pops up several dialogs as it installs, and you get no notification when it happens or when each dialog disappears.

If the dialog modality is an important enough issue to fix, change your command line options to:

- /HIDECONSOLE  to hide the initial console window that shows
- /Q to use quiet mode
- /INDICATEPROGRESS=0  to prevent any log output to the screen

Note that depending on the work the SQL install needs to do it will still sometimes show dialogs despite those settings - there's not much you can really do about that.

Note that you could also try using `/QS` - you may get a more consistent display of the progress dialog.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, Here This is the install command i have used..  InstallCommand =" /ACTION=Install /INSTANCENAME=customeName /FEATURES=SQLENGINE /QS /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS=true /SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Automatic /SAPWD=&quot;test@123&quot; /SECURITYMODE=SQL /SQLSVCACCOUNT=&quot;NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM&quot; /BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Automatic /ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN=true /TCPENABLED=1 /HIDECONSOLE" Please suggest me if anything needs to change to achieve my secnario. Thanks again

Comment: @Cegone Try adding `/INDICATEPROGRESS=0` (or `/INDICATEPROGRESS=FALSE`, it's the same), if you still don't have a satisfactory result then use just `/Q` instead of `/QS`.

Comment: /INDICATEPROGRESS=0 (or /INDICATEPROGRESS=FALSE) is not helped, but, /Q is quite working for SQL SERVER 2008 R2, but, We have chain installation in bundle, after SQL Server installation we are going to trigger another msi. So that msi's window also get behind the bundle installation window and we noticed the blinking intimation in task bar. Thank You